# Desktop gone after upgrade to Centos 6.6

Tags: centos, upgrade, desktop

I upgraded a local Centos VM from 6.5 to 6.6. After the update, no restart is needed and the desktop works. When I restart, I see the blue startup bar and CentOS 6.6 on the right side of it. When the bar is grey and startup has succeeded, the desktop should appear, but the screen stays at that bar.

I have snapshots and can go back to 6.5, and to the desktop right after upgrading.

How can I get the desktop back?

Comment: There is known issue when centos is installed on Raid partition.... check it.

Comment: You could add this to your answer as it might be overlooked for future visitors to this site. I don't use raid, it's a simple Virtualbox VM for testing, but it might be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem on my VM

This helped.

> ```
> 1. Start guest OS
> 2. When GRUB message comes on the screen press `Esc`
> 3. Type 'a' to append the word "single" to the end of the kernel statement
> 4. Press enter
> 5. At the 'root' prompt remove/rename Xorg configuration file:
>
>      mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bk
>
> 6. Reboot the system
> ```